# How to webscrape data from a webpage with dynamic HTML (Python)?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, dynamic-html

I'm trying to figure out how to scrape the data from the following url: https://www.aap.org/en-us/advocacy-and-policy/aap-health-initiatives/nicuverification/Pages/NICUSearch.aspx

Here is the type of data:

[image]

It appears that everything is populated from a database and loaded into the webpage via javascript.

I've done something similar in the past using `selenium` and `PhantomJS` but I can't figure out how to get these data fields in Python.

As expected, I can't use `pd.read_html` for this type of problem.

Is it possible to parse the results from:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url="https://www.aap.org/en-us/advocacy-and-policy/aap-health-initiatives/nicuverification/Pages/NICUSearch.aspx"

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get(url)
content = browser.page_source
```

Or maybe to access the actual underlying data?

If not, what are other approaches short of copy and pasting for hours?

## EDIT:

**Building on the answer below, from @thenullptr I have been able to access the material but only on page 1.  How can I adapt this to go across all of the pages [recommendations to parse properly]?  My end goal is to have this in a pandas dataframe**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.post(
    url = 'https://search.aap.org/nicu/', 
    data = {'SearchCriteria.Level':'1', 'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'}, 

) #key:value
html = r.text

# Parsing the HTML
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.split("</script>")[-1].strip(), "html")
div = soup.find("div", {"id": "main"})

div = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"blue-border panel list-group"})
def f(x):
    ignore_fields = ['Collapse all','Expand all']
    output = list(filter(bool, map(str.strip, x.text.split("\n"))))
    output = list(filter(lambda x: x not in ignore_fields, output))
    return output
results = pd.Series(list(map(f, div))[0])
```

Comment: If you're using a webdriver you can take advantage of `browser.find_elements_by_class_name('yourClassName')`, and if you need to wait for those elments to load you can do with `WebDriverWait(browser,secondsToWaitFloat)`. When you find elements by class name you get a list of elements on which you can call `get_attribute('innerText')` to get the innerText.

Comment: Try using the network tab on your browser dev tools to view what XHR calls are being made. There is probably a public API that the page is getting the information from which you can scrape.

Comment: @thenullptr there are a few `XHR` objects.  Here is the view: https://i.imgur.com/BddXtgA.png  How can I access these? What would I look for in particular (sorry, I've never used those objects before).

Comment: @libby How would you recommend finding the classes?  I've `inspected` individual elements using Google Chrome.  I found `<div class="col-md-7"><label>Email address: </label>emailaddresshere</div>` for example to get e-mail address.  Would the class I'm looking for be called `col-md-7`.  Can you show an example how I would extract that info? Thank you.

Comment: @O.rka I think this may help: https://imgur.com/a/C4fJQhn As far as I can see, the page (https://search.aap.org/nicu/) accepts a POST request to search, then as you can see in the screenshot, the page replies with the HTML which you can see in the response tab.

Comment: @O.rka the documentation here https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/getting_started_with_webdriver/locating_elements/ seems especially useful. For me, the process of web scraping is sometimes quite tedious. It's a lot of trial and error until I get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow on from my last comment, the below should give you a good starting point. When looking through the XHR calls you just want to see what data is being sent and received from each one to pinpoint the one you need. The below is the raw POST data being sent to the API when doing a search, it looks like you need to use at least one and include the last one.

```
{
    "SearchCriteria.Name": "smith",
    "SearchCriteria.City": "",
    "SearchCriteria.State": "",
    "SearchCriteria.Zip": "",
    "SearchCriteria.Level": "",
    "SearchCriteria.LevelAssigner": "",
    "SearchCriteria.BedNumberRange": "",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}
```

Here is a simple example of how you can send a post request using the requests library, the web page will reply with the raw data so you can use BS or similar to parse it to get the information you need.

```
import requests
r = requests.post('https://search.aap.org/nicu/', 
data = {'SearchCriteria.Name':'smith', 'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'}) #key:value
print(r.text)
```

prints  `<strong class="col-md-8 white-text">JOHN PETER SMITH HOSPITAL</strong>...`

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/

Comment: Thanks for this.  Which part are you actually using `data` dictionary?

Comment: data is just a parameter of the post function eg. `r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})` if that's what you mean

Comment: oh I don't know how I didn't catch that.  Do you recommend any way to parse the `r.text`? I thought the most effective way to do this was to start with `BedNumberRange` as 1 and then moving upwards.  Is this HTML or is this java script that is output? At first I thought this was XML and tried using XML trees but the format was off.

Comment: I'm trying to use `BeautifulSoup`: `soup = BeautifulSoup(html.split("</script>")[-1].strip(), "html")
div = soup.find("div", {"id": "main"})` Is this the best way to parse the results? I'm not sure how to use the Name search as I found a Name and then searched but got no results.  Although, your smith example works perfectly.

Comment: I'm also not clear how to access different page numbers

Comment: Nvm, I hacked something together.